# Call php file via axios requert has been blocked by CORS policy in VUE CLI 3

Tags: php, node.js, vue.js, command-line-interface, wampserver

I'm calling php file via axios get method in vue cli 3.
my servers: node js and wamp server
My app (**node**) path **http://localhost:8080/**  &
my **WAMP** path **http://localhost:80**.

Now I got `has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` and I saw **https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy** but it's not working for me.

In my **vue.config.js**

`module.exports = {
   devServer: {
     proxy: 'http://localhost/'
   }
}`

and my PHP file path in the views folder
*http://localhost:80/blog/src/views/php/imageUpload.php*

I need to know where I did mistake.

This is the error I'm getting:
[image: Click To see My error]

And this is my code:
[image: Click To see My axios code Picture]

Answer (score 0):

The CORS mechanism is used to enforce the client requests are coming from applications belonging to the same domain as the domain at which the server is deployed by default.In other words, it is to ensure that our own applications are only applications that access our API and to prevent applications belonging to other domains to access it. In your case, the Client application and Server application are using different ports. That breaks the rule

The requests are initiated from application running at 8080 to the server API running at 80, though they are running in the same localhost.The port differs. That's why the CORS errors are thrown.

Please set the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `localhost:8080` in the your PHP application to allow the cross domain requests.

[Please read the Functional overview of CORS mechanism here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)